# Using php what IP I will get when running script on localhost

Tags: php

I am trying to learn some PHP basics.
I am trying to get my system IP using this code-

```
$ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')?:
getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')?:
getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')?:
getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
echo $ip;
```

Now it is printing 127.0.0.1 
I am not sure why I am getting this IP and not 172.xxx.xx.xx something like that.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is localhost

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is just known as localhost.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Comment: While running on localhost, this is the exact IP you would get. The code gets the IP of the server i,e, your localhost and the IP of your Internet service provider

Comment: Once your code is live and available for public access, then you can get the IP address of the users. NOT possible on localhost

Comment: If you have another computer of phone connected to the same network, try accessing your server from that other machine. It should give you what you want to see

Comment: it's possible to give ip address in local. if ip address given means used via network group can access that project

Comment: So when my script is online, then it will print IP of user?